# Possible research directions in analysis?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am an undergraduate student who loves basic mathematics in the analysis branch, but I have learned that some directions, for example, harmonic analysis, are already well developed and difficult to make achievements. I want to know which direction in analysis has prospects and research value in today's era?

Comment: As far as my understanding of Math Overflow, this question is more appropriate for Math StackExchange. See https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/203/frequently-asked-questions-mathoverflow-faq Analysis is a huge branch with a long history and even in very developed areas there are breakthroughs that make long-standing questions amenable to further study or open up new interesting questions. So this problem will open up a lot of discussion.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you have access to math research journals, for example in your university's library? A good way to start getting an initial sense of research is to grab a journal volume from the shelf and read the first 1-2 pages of as many articles as you can. Read more than 2 pages if you understand it and you're interested, otherwise, on to the next paper. You're looking for a sense of what they're doing in the paper, why the authors think it's interesting/important, and how it fits into the broader landscape. As you read, you'll start to see connections and recurring themes.

Comment: Analysis is a huge subject and there are plenty of highly active areas. There’s no rush to focus on any direction. Just learn whatever seems interesting to you. A good blog to read is Terry Tao’s. He tries to explain things very simply and clearly and covers a very broad range of topics, not just his own research.

Comment: Currently closed on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4801686/possible-research-directions-in-analysis)

Comment: One suggestion is to focus on a real-world application that interests you a lot, and then work backwards to the math areas (if any) that study it. For example, turbulence is a physical phenomenon that will be around being studied for many years. It has many mathematical approaches devoted to its study, and so it narrows down the possibilities.

Comment: You need guidance from an advisor to pursue research in math.  If you feel that analysis is the field you are interested in, try to apply to graduate schools with a strong group in analysis.  Once you are in graduate school, ask an analyst to give you a research topic.

Answer (score 5):

I find that students often come in with these kinds of ideas, that almost everything is known, it's hard to do anything, the problems are mostly solved. Then they ask how to best position themselves to be at the forefront of a field whose scope they do not understand.

Let me assure everyone reading that nothing could be further from the truth: our understanding of analysis broadly is awful. We understand almost nothing. Open problems abound. This applies to most areas of analysis, certainly including any kind of harmonic analysis or PDE. It seems this is really not obvious to undergraduates and even to graduate students, but as you get older you will realize just how limited our toolkits are, how much there is out there that we do not even have the language to describe, how unsatisfactory many of the approaches we take to certain topics are.

The fact that the area is well-developed does not mean it's hard to "make achievements." On the contrary, it means there is a community of potential collaborators and mentors, as well as a ready audience for your papers. And just because something has been studied a lot does not mean there's nothing more to say, or that saying anything is extremely hard: for example, I've co-authored a paper about a "completely solved" topic, because we had new questions to ask in that context.

When choosing an area to work in, you should look for types of questions or types of objects you find genuinely interesting, and areas with good mentors available at your institution.

Do you find the basic idea of the Fourier transform interesting? Maximal functions, singular integrals? Badly behaved sets, boundary behavior of harmonic functions? Compact groups, Banach algebras? Wave and Schrodinger equations? These topics are all studied by excellent harmonic analysts working in 2023, they all have lots of open problems. Many have seen fantastic and surprising breakthroughs in the last few years.

Comment: My comment is a remark on the first paragraph of your answer. I do not remember the exact citation, but I remembered that once J. L. Lagrange complained that it was a pity not to have been born before, as all mathematical problems had nearly already been solved by the time he was able to confront with them (!). Nihil novi.